# What is the best way to restraint/secure a workstation?

Tags: linux, security, opensuse, account-restrictions, polkit

I want to prevent users to copy on usb devices and some others actions.
I was thinking of using polkit. Do you think it is a good solution or does someone know some alternatives ?

EDIT:

I also need to disable cd/dvd writing. How could I achieve this ? Polkit doesn't to be shipped with this kind of policy. I was thinking of disabling cdrecord for users.

Thanks

Comment: "Securing" a workstation has multiple meanings: (1) Securing the hardware, (2) Hardening the operating system, (3) Securing/limiting the available software. "and some other actions" is not helpful to get useful answers. Please consider giving more details.

Comment: I want to limit the risk of data leak/thievery on any support.

Answer (score 3):

There are very many ways of achieving this, you need to have an idea of what "some other actions" are before you can choose the solution.

Assuming that all you want is to prevent copying to usb devices, you could just prevent all usb storage devices from being mounted (blacklist that module). Or you could make the usb storage devices read-only (via udev), etc..

Comment: I have used polkit-1 and this policy **org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem***